# Indicative vs. subjunctive – was vs. were – “If a menu bar of personal commands was/were context-aware, then a “zoom-in” button would only appear if.”

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> If a menu bar of personal commands **was/were** context-aware, then a
>   “zoom-in” button would only appear if the current window or
>   application is something that you deem worthy of requiring a “zoom-in”
>   button, like a map or photo application.

At first, I thought it could be:

> “If a menu bar of personal commands **were** context-aware”.

I desire a context-sensitive menu bar in the newer Chrome OS operating system, so I thought that this was dealing with hypotheticals and wishful thinking (subjunctive mood?).

I also saw examples of “were” being used in alternate paths.

I went back to thinking of,

> “If a menu bar of personal commands **was** context-aware”

because the characteristic of the menu bar has not been decided yet.

I read about the example of,

> “I’m not rich”. “If I were rich”.

--

> “The bar is not context-sensitive.” “If the bar were context-sensitive”.

Actually, the menu bar is not not-context-sensitive”.

The menu bar is nothing.

It hasn’t been created yet.

It in fact could be context-sensitive.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Saying 'If John were there, he'd know what to do' doesn't **guarantee** that John's not there.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee it, but it strongly suggests it, or at least that the speaker doesn't believe John is there. It's illogical to say that if you know that John is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct to use "were" because you set up the clause regarding the button as contingent on a conditional. "If A was B, then X" implies a construction in which X can be observed or evaluated in order to determine the nature of A at the time of consequence.

However, if you're planning to write this out for anyone you could avoid all ambiguity by preferring "In a context-sensitive menu bar, a 'zoom-in' button will/should..." or alternatively "If a menu bar is context-sensitive, then its 'zoom-in' button only appears ..."

One more thought, which may perhaps lend some clarity by analogue:

Consider the use of "was" vs "had been":

*If a menu bar of personal commands was context aware*

*If a menu bar of personal commands had been context aware*

The fact that they refer to a conditional that has already evaluated is evident when you consider that they are naturally better-suited to use of "the menu bar" than "a menu bar", because of the implicit specificity of something that has already occurred. The difference here is that "was" is neutral toward the *result* of that conditional -- whereas "had been" denotes that the conditional evaluated false at the time.

Comment: I don't see how the use of *had been* can possibly be justified in this context; *had been* is past, and the OP is asking about (possibly hypothetical) *future* events.

Comment: right, this would not be applicable for just that reason - I only brought it up because of its relationship to "was" which the OP did consider. It is precisely because of this relationship that I would in no uncertain terms similarly rule out "was" as an option here.

Comment: You don't need to separate edits: the history is available (if the edit occurs after the first five minutes). Just make the answer coherent and complete.